# Saving OS X Game Data Using NSData and NSMutableArrays

Tags: objective-c, macos, save

I am trying to store the hi-score of several levels in a NSMutableArray, which will then be saved in a file in the Documents folder. I know I can use plists, but I don't want the content to be modified by the user. It appears that `NSMutableArray *hiscore` is not being initialized and I'm not sure how to fix this. For primitives it seems fine, but for objects it's not working.

**GameData.h**

```
@interface GameData : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (assign, nonatomic) int level;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *hiscore;

+(instancetype)sharedGameData;
-(void)save;
-(void)reset;

@end
```

**GameData.m**

```
#import "GameData.h"

@implementation GameData

static NSString* const GameDataLevelKey = @"level";
static NSString* const GameDataHiscoreKey = @"hiscore";

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _level = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: GameDataLevelKey];
        _hiscore = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:GameDataHiscoreKey];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)sharedGameData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

+(instancetype)loadInstance {
    NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [GameData filePath]];
    if (decodedData) {
        GameData* gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
        return gameData;
    }

    return [[GameData alloc] init];
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.level forKey: GameDataLevelKey];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.hiscore forKey:GameDataHiscoreKey];
}

+(NSString*)filePath {
    static NSString* filePath = nil;
    if (!filePath) {
        filePath =
        [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"];
    }
    return filePath;
}

-(void)save {
    NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    [encodedData writeToFile:[GameData filePath] atomically:YES];
    /*[_hiscore writeToFile:[GameData filePath] atomically:YES];*/
}

-(void)reset {
    self.level = 0;
}

@end
```

**LevelScene.m**

```
#import "GameData.h"
...
[[[GameData sharedGameData] hiscore] addObject:@1500];
[[GameData sharedGameData] save];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

First, in `initWithCoder:`, if there's no game file already (as would be the case on first launch, or if it was saved with no scores), `_hiscore` will end up `nil`, so you won't be able to add any scores to it. I'd check it for nil after the call to `decodeObjectForKey:`, and if it's nil, initialize it to an empty array.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _level = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: GameDataLevelKey];
        _hiscore = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:GameDataHiscoreKey];
        if( _hiscore == nil ) {
            _hiscore = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Second, GameData owns `_hiscore`, so it's going to need a strong reference to it.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *hiscore;
```

**Edit:**
The general rule (see the [Memory Management section of Apple's Cocoa Core Competencies Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html)) is:

> You own any object you create by allocating memory for it or copying it.

That generally means that any object you create with methods containing `alloc` or `copy`, but it also pertains to convenience methods like `array`, etc. Note that `[NSMutableArray array]` is exactly equivalent to `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`; the only reason to use the former is that it's less typing (which many, including myself, are a fan of).

Then,

> If you own an object, either by creating it or expressing an ownership interest, you are responsible for releasing it when you no longer need it.

Pre-ARC, that meant calling `release` or `autorelease` on it.

In an ARC world, memory management is *mostly* taken care of for you, but you still need to kinda understand the concepts behind it for it to make sense. Basically, if you create an object (using methods containing `alloc` or `copy`, or convenience methods such as `array`), then you own that object. You express ownership of that object by creating a `strong` reference to it. If you fail to do so (say, your reference is `weak` or `assign`), then ARC will (rightly) assume you're done with that object, and will release it as soon as it decides you're done with it. In the code above, it's a safe bet ARC chose to release `_hiscore` as soon as `initWithCoder` returned. Later, your code tries to access `_hiscore`, but it's already been released, and so you crash.

Without code to initialize `_highscore`, it *didn't* crash. Because `_highscore` was always `nil`, and sending a message to `nil` is totally fine in Objective-C; nothing happens. But if you do initialize it, and only have it set to `assign`, then it's no longer `nil`. Once ARC releases it, `_highscore` is pointing to an object that no longer exists, and that's what causes the crash.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, I had tried to initialize the array before, but then my app would just crash. It was the whole lack of a `strong` reference that caused the issue. Thanks so much. I've been trying to wrap my head around these concepts. One follow-up question before I accept the answer: why did the absence of a strong reference make the difference here?

Comment: Not enough room in comments to see what I want to say, see edit above.

Comment: dude! That makes complete sense now. Thank you for the thorough explanation...I won't be making that mistake again!